# Using (Venmo) OAuth API with Ionic Framework

Tags: oauth, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, venmo

I'm currently having some issues using the Venmo API in the context of an app built on the Ionic framework. I'm currently building an Ionic app, which uses the [Venmo OAuth API](https://developer.venmo.com/docs/quickstart), and trying to test it out on my iPhone. My Venmo authentication flow currently goes like this: I use the Cordova "[In App Browser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)" plugin to open the Venmo OAuth sign-in page in-app, which redirects the user back to my app with a query parameter specifying an access token, allowing me to make requests to Venmo's API endpoints on the user's behalf. When I run my Ionic app on my Mac (via `ionic serve`) and access it via a web browser, I'm able to use the OAuth API (as you would expect). However, when I run my app on my iPhone, I can't get the app to work with OAuth API because the Venmo authorization page, opened with the In App Browser plugin, can't redirect back to my app. Again, this flow works in browser, but it fails on my iPhone.

To my knowledge, it looks like the OAuth API is the only way I can interact with Venmo through an Ionic app. This is presenting a problem because the "In App Browser" plugin doesn't allow Venmo's authorization page to redirect back to my app when testing on an iPhone. I'm open to trying this process any other way. I see in the Venmo docs that there's an iOS SDK but I don't think I can use that in any way in an Ionic app. If someone has an example of authenticating with other OAuth services in an Ionic app, that would also be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You try using this for Venmo?: https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth